# Como limitar um comando por tempo? Php

Tags: php

Gostaria que essa função do meu php, só pudesse ser usado a cada 3minutos, como faço isso?

Comando é esse.

```
case strpos($mensagem, '/metar') === 0:
            if(strlen($mensagem)>6 && strlen($mensagem)<=11){
                $airport = substr($mensagem, 7);
                sendParse($chatid, $met->icaoMetar($airport)."\n \n".$met->icaoTAF($airport)."\n\n @OneThousandChat");
            }
```

Comment: Global ou por usuário? pode gravar na sessão ou no banco de dados, e fazer uma validação antes de fazer a chamada, pelo que sei a única maneira é essa.

Comment: Global, nao tem banco de dados.

Comment: Depende do que a sua função faz, se ela for um loop que roda infinitamente pode ser que seja possivel implementar, caso contrário será difícil.

Comment: Negativo, comando é executado, ai ele mostra as informaçoes, só vai mostrar novamente quando comando for executado novamente

Comment: Não dá pra presumir nada se não soubermos o funcionamento do código, você apenas esta afirmando porque sabe o que fez, o que eu disse tem fundamento no que é possivel entender, e tem um detalhe, PHP não é assincrono, logo algum tipo de operação terá que ocorrer, ou recursão ou loop para chegar, ou você quer apenas uma checagem, mas da forma que esta não dá pra dizer qual é a solução para o seu caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer da seguinte forma:

```
if (! $_SESSION['dh_acesso'])
{
    $_SESSION['dh_acesso'] = new DateTime();

    $permite = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $dh_atual = new DateTime();

    if ($dh_atual->diff($_SESSION['dh_acesso'])->i > 3)
    {
        $permite = TRUE; // Passou 3 min., então pode permitir...

        unset($_SESSION['dh_acesso']); // Esvazia a sessão para um novo ciclo
    }
    else
    {
        $permite = FALSE;
    }
}

if ($permite)
{
    // Chama a função aqui...
}
```

Na primeira tentativa, será criada a `$_SESSION['dh_acesso']` que irá armazenar a data e hora do acesso e o *flag* `$permite` será definido como `TRUE`. Em seguida, sua função poderá ser executada.

Já na segunda tentativa, o `else` será executado, ou seja, será feita a validação do tempo em decorrência da `$_SESSION['dh_acesso']`. Portanto, se os 3 minutos tiverem sido ultrapassados, sua função poderá ser executada e a sessão será esvaziada para iniciar um novo ciclo. Caso contrário, haverá o impedimento da execução.

Lembre-se de dar o `session_start()` e configurar o `date_default_timezone_set()` corretamente.

É uma ideia. :)